# Handle incoming HTTP request with Socket.io in Node js app

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I have a node app that should receive request from another app through a HTTP GET request `/api/users?data=68` and display the data in real time.I have api/users route that handle incoming HTTP request. To start with i have node app that works with socket.io But now i want to handle Http request.Here is my code

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var server   = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);
    var port = process.env.PORT || 8080
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    var router = express.Router();

    router.get('/api/users', function(req, res) {
    var query = req.param('data');
    io.emit("chat message","some msg");
    });

    io.on('connection', function(socket){
     console.log('client connected');
     socket.on('pass data from HTTP request to the view', function(data){
     console.log(data);
     });

   });

     app.use(router);

     server.listen(port)
```

**Client.js**

```
 var socket = io();
  socket.on('chat message', function (message) {
    //socket.emit('chat message', { my: 'world' });
    console.log('received ');
    });
```

How do i pass data from /api/users/ route to socket connection?Thank you in adavance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send the data to all socket.io connected clients, you can do:

```
io.emit("someMsg", someData);
```

If you want to send only to only a specific socket.io connection, then you need to be able to get that particular socket which you can do via a socket.id or some other way you keep track of which socket is which.

Comment: So do you mean put `io.emit("someMsg", someData);` inside `/api/users` route? Because the question is how do i get the data in `/api/users` route to socket connection so that i display it in real time.

Comment: @sparks - Sorry, but I don't understand WHO you are trying to send the data to and I don't understand when you want to send data.  Remember, your server can have many clients connected to it via socket.io at the same time.  Also, if you just want to get data back to only the client that issues the `/api/users` request, then it would be a whole lot simpler to just return that data from the API request.  That's what HTTP requests are for.

Comment: So basically the client who fire `/api/users` is another external app. It just supply the data and i want to display the data to the browser for everybody to see  through socket connection in real time.

Comment: @sparks - As my answer says, if you're trying to send the data to ALL connected clients, then whenever your server has data it wants to send to all the clients it can do `io.emit("someMsg", someData);` and that message and data will be sent to all connected clients.  If the place where the server gets the data is inside the `/api/users` request handler, then that's where you would put the `io.emit(...)` call.  If the server acquired the data some other way (such as from some other outside source), then that's where you would put the `io.emit(...)` call.

Comment: oh ok, I have been trying to do that though it is not working at all.Maybe something wrong on my client code.I am going to add the client code please see above .

Comment: @sparks - Are you seeing the `console.log('client connected');` from your server?  Do you know for sure that the browser is connected via socket.io to your server?

Comment: Yes, client is connected is logged.

Comment: @sparks - Well the code you've shown with the `io.emit()` I suggested added where you added it will work if there are no other errors preventing some of it from running properly.  So, you're going to have to do some debugging to find out what isn't running properly. I would probably start by adding a `console.log("data sent")` right before the `io.emit()` on the server to verify that is running and then looking at the browser-side network trace to verify that a socket.io packet is arriving (it is a little more complicated to see incoming socket.io packets in the debugger, but it can be done).

Comment: It seems like there is a problem with client code because even when i do io.emit within `.on(connection callback )` on the server ,  the client doesn't respond